# как сделать первую букву заглавной в элементе вектора? С++

Tags: c++

у меня задача, по которой необходимо сделать двумерный вектор элементы которого латинские буквы (кодировка ASCII)
каждый элемент вектора должен состоять их 4-х букв и первая - заглавная
как мне сделать первую букву заглавной и как поправить диапазон генерации? (у меня рандомятся только строчные)
`(97) + rand() % 26`

Comment: `::toupper(char);` делает букву заглавной

Comment: извини, а можно как-нибудь по-другому?

Comment: А что с этим не так?

Comment: этой функцией не пользовался ранее просто

Comment: как можно применить его здесь? 
`for (int i = 0;i < a;++i)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < b;++j)
  {
   for (int k = 0;k<6;++k)
   {
    h[i][j] +=  (97) + rand() % 26;
   }
  }
  cout << endl;
 }`

i, j - организация по строкам и столбцам, k для элементов